# Conjugacy of two permutations in $A_n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

This may be easier questions; but I did not find a reference.

(If this is trivial or repeated, and if one states the reference, I will delete the question.)

In $A_4$, we know $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,3,2)$ although have same cycle structure, they are not conjugate.

Other situation: suppose for $\sigma\in A_n$, its conjugacy class in $S_n$ splits in $A_n$:
$$
\sigma^{S_n} =\sigma^{A_n}\cup \sigma^{\tau A_n}
$$
where $\tau$ is an odd permutation.

If $\theta$ is a permutation of same cycle type as $\sigma$, how to detect whether $\theta$ falls in $\sigma^{A_n}$ or $\sigma^{\tau A_n}$?

(Shortly: When two permutations in $A_n$, having same cycle structure are conjugate in $A_n$? Can we find a conjugating element?)

Comment: Yes, there are many duplicates, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2073273/given-two-permutations-in-a-n-of-same-cycle-type-when-they-are-conjugate-in), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144686/conjugacy-classes-in-a-n), and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159123/question-about-conjugacy-class-of-alternating-group?noredirect=1&lq=1), etc. Did you search already?

Comment: In the first two, I did not found complete answer (before posting question); third link, I will see. (Most of the questions are: when a conjugacy class of $S_n$ splits in $A_n$; but I was looking little different than this!)

Comment: You can specify *what exactly* is missing for you in the answers. This would make your question more to the point. Actually, did you read the [GP page](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Splitting_criterion_for_conjugacy_classes_in_the_alternating_group)? It is also very clear on how to decide whether or not a conjugacy class splits in $A_n$.

Comment: The conjugacy classes of $A_n$ are the same as the conjugacy classes of $S_n$, except when a class of $S_n$ splits in $A_n$, so anything that tells you when a class of $S_n$ splits in $A_n$ tells you everything there is to know.

Comment: @Gerry: So a class of $(1,2,3)$ in $S_4$ splits in $A_4$. So, we ask: whether $(2,3,4)$ is conjugate to $(1,2,3)$ in $A_4$ or not? I could not see any way for this!

Comment: OK, I understand now, you want to know, when a class in $S_n$ splits, which members go into each of the two classes in $A_n$. In that particular case, the class of $123$ is $123,134,142,243$. I found those by conjugating $123$ with the four elements of the $(xx)(xx)$ subgroup of $A_4$. I don't know what the general answer is. (But I'd still be surprised if there wasn't already an answer elsewhere on this website.)

Comment: Fix representatives for each conjugacy class of $S_n$. If the class is nonsplit, the class of $g \in A_n$ is determined by the cycle structure. Otherwise, let $x \in A_n$ be the representative for the $S_n$-class of $g$. Then the class of $g$ is determined by the parity of a element conjugating $g$ to $x$. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4509455/conjugacy-of-two-even-permutations-in-a-n/4509467#4509467) and the answer there which hopefully helps.